# Laravel - Queued cookies and middleware

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Adding a cookie in the cookies queued of laravel lead to have them in the queue in the next response...

```
Cookie::queue(cookie('test', 'test', 1));
return $next($request);
... 
Controller things
...
View
{{ dd(Cookie::getQueuedCookies()) }}
```

which show :

```
array:1 [
   'test' => Cookie{...}
]
```

Is there no way of setting a cookie for the next response than adding

```
next($request->cookie(cookie(...)));
```

in the middleware ?

Comment: do you mean no other way to set it in the middleware or also to set in in the controller?

Comment: Yes exactly, with something like the queue

Answer (score 0):

You can also set cookies in your controller:

```
public function someAction() 
{
    return response()
        ->json($result)
        ->withCookie('secret.submitted', $secret->code, 60);
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/52-how-to-use-cookies

```
public function someAction()
{
    return response('Hello World')->cookie(
        'name', 'value', $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly
    );
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#cookies

Comment: So I can't deal with the queue if the goal is not the next request ?

Comment: You mean you want to set a cookie in the middleware and get it in the controller in the same request?

Comment: Nop, I mean set a cookie in the middleware and retrieve him in the view as a cookie and not a cookie in the queue (but I assume that not the logic laravel longed for)

Comment: Have you tired the php functions `setcookie` and `$_COOKIE` to handle cookies? But is there a disadvantage to handle it in a queue?

Comment: I try to stay in the delimitation of the framework, the disadvantage is that I'm using it for token values that have to be up to date